# OSX Unrecognized Arguments Terminal Render

Tags: blend-files, command-line, network, osx

I am trying to a run a slave blend to connect to a server. I made the slave and it runs on windows and will run fine on when I run in blender and start the service manually with a GUI. How when I try to run with a slightly modified command I run into errors.

```
open /Applications/Blender/blender "/Users/schultz/Desktop/Blender/slave.blend" --addons netrender -a -noaudio -nojoystick
```

When I try to run 
terminal I get this error:

> open: unrecognized option '--addons'

I also tried to do an applescipt version

```
do shell script "open -a /Applications/Blender/blender "/Users/schultz/Desktop/Blender/slave.blend" --addons netrender -a -noaudio -nojoystick"
```

And that yielded

> The operation couldn't be completed. ( com.apple.Automator error -212)

If anyone could inform me how to either send arguments to open or how to fix what I have to do that would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried to run it with exec and supply the arguments after

```
exec "/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender" [-b "/Users/schultz/Desktop/Blender/slave.blen" netrender -a -noaudio -nojoystick]
```

and that got me this error:

> ```
> unknown option 'n': skipping  
> unknown option 'n': skipping
> wm_main_playanim_intern: '/Users/schultz/' not an image file
>
> [Process completed]
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with Blender. It's with the command you're running. Using the `open` command is fine for opening applications, but it doesn't allow you to pass arguments to the application (as far as I know).

You want to call the executable directly with:
`/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender "/Users/schultz/Desktop/Blender/slave.blend" --addons netrender -a -noaudio -nojoystick`

Calling the executable itself will allow you to pass arguments to Blender.

Comment: Yea I figured it shortly after once I realized it was OSX not Blender and it getting arguments. Thank you none the less!